# When to dispose wcf object with async pattern

Tags: .net, wcf, idisposable

Supposing I start off with the synchronous version:

```
 using(var svc = new ServiceObject()) {
     var result = svc.DoSomething();
     // do stuff with result
 }
```

I wind up with

```
var svc = new ServiceObject();
svc.BeginDoSomething(async => {
    var result = svc.EndDoSomething(async);
    svc.Dispose();
    // do stuff with result
},null);
```

1) Is this the correct place to call Dispose()?

2)  is there a way to use using() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Rotem Bloom's blog:
 http://caught-in-a-web.blogspot.com/2008/05/best-practices-how-to-dispose-wcf.html

**Best Practices: How to Dispose WCF clients**

Use of the using statement (Using in Visual Basic) is not recommended for Dispose WCF clients. This is because the end of the using statement can cause exceptions that can mask other exceptions you may need to know about.

```
using (CalculatorClient client = new CalculatorClient())
{
...
} // this line might throw

Console.WriteLine("Hope this code wasn't important, because it might not happen.");

The correct way to do it is:
try
{
    client.Close();
}
catch (CommunicationException)
{
    client.Abort();
}
catch (TimeoutException)
{
    client.Abort();
}
catch
{
     client.Abort();
     throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your service won't be accessing any unmanaged resources, why not let it fall out of scope and let the GC do its thing?